# Projection (or idempotent) graph of a $C^*$ algebra(or a ring)

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

In the literature, are there some research around a directed graph associated to a $C^*$ algebra or a ring $A$ whose vertices are projections or idempotents of $A$ and $e$ is connected to $f$ iff $ef=fe=f$? What properties of this graph reflect some part of structure of $A$?

Answer (score 3):

Please check out this book:

> Goodearl, Kenneth R. Von Neumann regular rings. Vol. 4. London: Pitman, 1979.

I'm pretty sure I remember this being discussed (but in terms of a partial ordering, which you can re-interpret as a digraph).

I do not recall specifically projections being analyzed in terms of this partial order, because the book isn't specifically about $C^\ast$ algebras, but it should be general enough to cover the basics, and informative enough to point you toward the specifics.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.